# Can I update by query in ElasticSearch Bulk Api?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

Lets say I have 1000 users, each user has 50 documents(each document embeds user object having name and email), I need to update name and email for a set of users.

I would like to use Bulk Api, but it seems like bulk API only supports "_id" as the parameter. I would like to make a query instead

For example: I would like to do,

```
POST _bulk
{ "update" : {"query" : {"terms": {"userId": "25"}}, "_type" : "comments", "_index" : "comments"} }
{ "doc" : {"user.name" : "new name"} }
```

instead of

```
POST _bulk
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "comments", "_index" : "comments"} }
{ "doc" : {"user.name" : "new name"} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) for this purpose:

```
POST comments/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.user.name = newName",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "newName": "new name"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "userId": "25"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to do the same for all all users, Can I put the same query in bulk api ?

Comment: If you need to do this for all users, you don't need scripting, you can simply issue a partial document update via the bulk API.

Comment: Bulk API we need to mention the id of the document, but I dont have the id.

Comment: Then there's no way you can use the bulk API. where do the new name and the userId come from?

Comment: they come from another micro-service

Comment: Can you somehow make a mapping between userid et new name in a separate CSV file?